# Could you hack a gas station's fuel dispenser?

Tags: vulnerability

This might be a dumb question, but still, would it be possible for someone to hack in to a [fuel dispenser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_dispenser) and change the price, fuel consumed, etc?

Comment: The short answer is yes.  Any system can be hacked.  The long answer is going to depend on your threat model: who is doing it and why are they doing it. Based on that, it becomes a matter of is it economically viable for them to do so.

Comment: @user52472 thank you, but I am looking for a specific answer, whether there is an existing flaw or someone actually done it for X reasons.

Comment: The specific flaw is that the pumps are on a computer network that has a person on it.  The same way that the devices on your network can be hacked because you are on it ... and I can get you to click this [link](https://google.com/)

Comment: CaffeineAddiction Good point.

Comment: maybe not the fuel consumed; pumps use mechanical logging to avoid/detect such cheating.

Comment: dandavis Well, atleast in theory you could sabotage competitor's fuel price, so you could hurt their reputation or something.

Comment: i saw an open pump the other day (servicing) and it had three old-school "odometers", one above each pump. The price is doable for sure: i've seen hourly staff lower the price moments after the gas station across the street changed, so there's not a ton of authentication. How long before HQ noticed though?

Comment: @dandavis well, imagine if this would be possible on a massive scale, so many millions of $ would be lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to any question of the type "Is it possible to hack X?" is yes. It might be hard. It might only be possible under certain limiting conditions (e.g. you might need physical access if it's not connected to a network). It might require very specific skills or information (e.g. knowledge of whatever software a fuel pump runs). But it is still possible.

That said, it's probably easier to just pay your bill.